# refugees of/from Afghanistan - same meaning?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

Can one use a)

> This is a place where refugees **of** Afghanistan are sheltered.

instead of b)?

> This is a place where refugees **from** Afghanistan are sheltered.

I think 'refugees of Afghanistan' could mean 'refugees who are in Afghanistan', but could it also mean 'refugees from Afghanistan'?

Comment: I do not think they can used interchangeably.

Comment: They have come _from_ Afghanistan and are taking refuge _from_ the dangers there. They were formerly citizens/residents _of_ Afghanistan, but we would describe them as _Afghan refugees_ rather than using _of_.